Infinite access for refresh token for google apis (gmail)
I have a server side application which needs to access  emails of all employees of my organization for statistics purpose (using gmail apis) . I am going to  use  oauth to get the access of my employees gmail accounts by sending them oauth authorization links over mail. Is there a direct way to access my employees emails using admin account api's ? If I take individual consents from them, I want to make the refresh token life time infinite so that I dont need to send mails to my employees again and again for their oauth consent approval. Or there is any other way like running crons to update the refresh token for individual user to make its lifetime forever.
I havent tried anything yet, I need this for client project


I have a server side application which needs to access emails of all employees of my organization for statistics purpose (using gmail apis).

If this is google workspace you should use a service account with domain wide delegation.

I am going to use oauth to get the access of my employees gmail accounts by sending them oauth authorization links over mail.

That should work.

Is there a direct way to access my employees emails using admin account api's?

Yes if you have google workspace then you can use a service account.

If I take individual consents from them, I want to make the refresh token life time infinite so that I dont need to send mails to my employees again and again for their oauth consent approval.

Refresh tokens in production ready apps don't expire as long as you use it once every six months.

Thank you for your response. So Lets consider I am using admin google sdk admin Api's.  I want to first retrieve all the email addresses in my organization, then retrieve all the email data (inbox, sent, drafts and all) for each user retrieved in first step. What would be the steps here. Which Api's should be used ?

Go with the admin sdk and get a list of your users manage-users then go with the gmail api and get access to their email Just make sure that you configure Domain wide delgation to your service account properly
